# MATLAB: How to run a different file than the one being edited?

Tags: matlab

I (unfortunately) have a MATLAB project with two files, **main.m** and **function.m**.
I spent my time editing **function.m**, which is called several times from **main.m**. When I press **F5** on the keyboard, it runs the current file (**function.m**) so i need to keep changing back to main.m to run the project, which is irritating. I am used to eclipse that will run the last launched.

Is there a way to effect that behaviour in MATLAB?

If any potential employers are reading this, please note that I am forced to use this program (which charges customers for access to thread-safe primitives) against my will.

Comment: how is your question actually related to (Matlab) programming per se? Wouldn't, for example, `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/` be a better place to ask this kind of question? Thanks

Comment: I don't know, would it? The entry point to execution of a program seems pretty related to programming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with clicking a button instead of hitting F5, you could make a "Run main" button in the shortcuts toolbar. In the main Matlab window, right-click the menu and turn on the Shortcuts toolbar if it's not on already. Right-click the shortcut toolbar, "new shortcut", put "Run main" in the label, and enter "main()" for the callback. This will work regardless of what file you're editing, and you could set up additional shortcuts for alternate run configurations if you get to that point.

I don't think you can define key bindings for these shortcuts. But if you really want it, Yair Altman's Undocumented Matlab site has a [hack for adding arbitrary user defined key bindings](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/editormacro-v2-setting-command-window-key-bindings/) that could probably be used here.

Answer (score 9):

Choose *"Edit Run Configurations for function.m"* in the run menu and write your custom line (main). See attached image.
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that is a new feature, since I'm stuck on 7.4.0 and it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: I guess the same. I am using 2010a.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the windows into two external edit windows and use `Alt + Tab` to switch and then `F5`?

Comment: You can switch between files in the editor with Ctrl + PgUp and Ctrl + PgDown, without having to pop them in to external windows. It cycles through them in tab order.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `main` at the command-line?  And from then on, press the up key and hit enter?

Comment: I don't think that is any easier than clicking on the tab for the main file, and then pressing F5.